# C++ Doubly Linked List (Deleting First Node Causes Crash)

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm building a doubly-linked list using C++, and I have the basic Chain and Node structures up and running ––

The Nodes have 2 pointers – one for left one for right – and 1 integer for the data to be held. A constructor and a destructor are both included, and the format looks like so:

`Node(const int e, Node* left, Node* right)`

The Chain has 4 functions I'm trying to implement: **InsertBack**, **InsertAfter**, **Delete**, and **DeleteAll**. The first two work as planned, but here is the code for **InsertBack** because I think it is relevant to the problem (shown below). I use a pointer named `head` (declared as `Node* head = NULL;`) to keep track of the first node, and scan through the linked list starting from it every time. The if-else logic here is to determine if the first node is being created.

```
void Implement::InsertBack(int num)
{
    if(head == NULL){
        head = new Node(num, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else{
    Node* tmp = this->head;
    while(tmp->right != NULL) {
        tmp = tmp->right;
    }
    tmp->right = new Node(num, tmp, NULL);
  }
}
```

My problem lies in **Delete** and **DeleteAll** causing the compiled exe file to crash *when it deletes the first node* (i.e. the one I'm pointing to with `head`). Below is my implementation of **Delete**, which is supposed to delete the first node with data of `int num` that it scans through from the start (and do nothing if `int num` isn't found):

```
void Implement::Delete(int num)
{
  Node* tmp = this->head;
  while(tmp != NULL) {
    if(tmp->data != num){
      tmp = tmp->right;
    }
    else{
      if(tmp->left == NULL){
        head = tmp->right;
        delete tmp;
        break;
      }
      else if(tmp->right == NULL){
        Node* leftnode = tmp->left;
        leftnode->right = NULL;
        delete tmp;
        break;
      }
      else{
        Node* leftnode = tmp->left;
        Node* rightnode = tmp->right;
        leftnode->right = rightnode;
        rightnode->left = leftnode;
        delete tmp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I designed it to scan through the entire loop, moving to the next node when the number isn't the same, and dealing with 3 different cases when it finds the number: (1) If the node is the first node / (2) If the node is the last node / (3) If the node is any other node in between. In each case, the `tmp` pointer always points to the node that needs to be deleted.

As for the **DeleteAll** function, I simply altered **Delete** to continue scanning even after finding a node with the right number. It fails on all inputs so far; the code looks like this:

```
void Implement::DeleteAll(int num)
{
  Node* tmp = this->head;
  while(tmp != NULL) {
    if(tmp->data != num){
      tmp = tmp->right;
    }
    else{
      if(tmp->left == NULL){
        Node* rightnode = tmp->right;
        head = tmp->right;
        delete tmp;
        Node* tmp = rightnode;
      }
      else if(tmp->right == NULL){
        Node* leftnode = tmp->left;
        leftnode->right = NULL;
        delete tmp;
        break;
      }
      else{
        Node* leftnode = tmp->left;
        Node* rightnode = tmp->right;
        leftnode->right = rightnode;
        rightnode->left = leftnode;
        delete tmp;
        Node* tmp = rightnode;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out the problem that causes **Delete** and **DeleteAll** to crash. Any form of help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: Which line is causing the crash? Have you stepped through with a debugger? A [MCVE] is invaluable for tracking down a run-time problem.

Comment: When deleting the `head` you set the next node (`head->right`) as the new `head` but you do not seem to set that node's `left` to `null`. It still points to the deleted node.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks so much for that link! It's super helpful, I'll work on it right away. And yes, you're absolutely right, my bad for the sloppy logic hole. I'll fix that now and see if it does the trick.

Comment: Quick update: The bug remains. I'll work on that MCV method now.

Comment: @BrianHo -- Using the terms `right` and `left` are more appropriate for a binary tree, not linked list.  For a linked list, the terms that are more appropriate are `previous` and `next` or similar words.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, I'll make a note of that :)

Comment: @Brain Ho check into smart pointers, especially unique_ptr. They manage resource they point to as well, so you won't need to use new/delete in your code. With combination of unique_ptr and raw pointers you can write a nice double-linked list. (assuming you are using at least c++11)